# Pearson correlation for comparing models

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation, predictive-models, pearson-r

I want to know if I can use Pearson correlation coefficient (i.e. whether my PS satisfies its usage or I need to look at other correlation measures) to study the extent of correlation between 2 vectors of data:

PS: I have 10 ML models and 100 data sets, and build all models on all data sets. I want to see how correlated the model predicted average error (on all 100 data sets) between any two models are. There will be ${}^{10}C_2$ model pairs. The idea is that if model $i$ and model $j$ show similar average errors for each data set, then I should see a large correlation in average errors of these two models. Can I use Pearson correlation for this task?

Comment: You could, but Pearson correlation measures linearity of relationship rather than agreement of values. Concordance correlation is a better measure than Pearson correlation. Whether average error is a good way to assess your models and whether there is a different measure that comes closer to your situation are broader questions. The suggested duplicate isn't answering the same question, but its answers and its links point you in the right direction.

Comment: While concordance is a better measure for agreement of values, I guess when I am using 10 "different" models, I should not be expecting identical average errors (or, as mentioned by Nick, some other evaluative measure like R2 etc.) for 2 different models on the same data set. Nevertheless, my aim is to find "similar" performing models, hence don't you feel that pearson correlation should be the way to go, @Nick?

Comment: As said, no. Indeed, your expectation that models will have quite different typical errors is precisely why concordance correlation is the tool of choice. There is just one advantage of Pearson correlation here, that your readers are much more likely to have heard of it than concordance correlation. In principle Pearson correlation is the wrong answer for your problem which is to assess agreement. The cited duplicate and its links say much more.